# Форма ТОРГ-12 в html

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Подскажите, может кто-то уже использовал: нужна форма ТОРГ-12 в html-формате. Просьба не писать "загугли", "google для чего?" или еще лучше "открой обычную ТОРГ-12 и выбери <сохранить как>" - пробовал, вся форма к чертям сбилась.
Буду благодарен!

Comment: видимо нужно уточнить, что же это за форма такая. Не с 1с случайно?

Comment: @KoVadim нет, не 1С. http://schetov.ru/blanks/torg12/

Comment: сохраните как html, а также сохраните все css и js. Потом проверьте, что пути все верные.

Comment: @KoVadim пробовал говорю же, верстка всей таблицы слетела. Пути проверял, Excel не сохраняет в css, он в js все сует, а тот потом инициализирует.

Comment: я специально сохранил в хроме, поправил один урл к картинке (он начинался с images/ на правильный, локальный). И визуально все стало очень похоже.

Comment: @KoVadim просто нужна практически точная копия, документ как никак.

Comment: Вот как раз для этого и используют pdf. А то, что html будет выглядеть немножко не так - не имеет значения.

html не предназначен для печати "точных документов".